# Link Facebook messenger sender id with Facebooks fbid

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I have a `django` app that allows users to login using facebook. It also allows users to communicate with the app using facebook messenger. Now the users `id` for logging in and messenger are different. I want to be able to link the two together.

I've found this doc which should connect the two accounts but I keep getting errors https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/connecting-accounts

I'm using

```
GET /{user-id}
    ?fields=name,is_payment_enabled,ids_for_apps,ids_for_pages
    &access_token=[page_access_token]
    &appsecret_proof=[appsecrete_proof]
```

keep getting the following error

> {u'error': {u'message': u"Unsupported get request. Object with ID
>   '1569748269763653' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing
>   permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph
>   API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
>   u'code': 100, u'type': u'GraphMethodException', u'fbtrace_id':
>   u'BEurWnDCwuu'}}

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue before when building a chat app in Django using the Messenger platform api.

First make sure your Facebook app is published. You will see if it is on the dashboard of the app in your Facebook developers account. It should say "This app is public and available to all users" underneath the app title.

My issue turned out to be the actual Facebook Page's permissions. I was able to get rid of the graph error by updating two of the page permissions here (go to the Facebook page -> settings ):

[image]

Make sure these two are set as shown. Also make sure that the Facebook page is published(you will see this at the top of settings).

Should be good to go.